# Sum with index as derivative order

Tags: python, sympy

I want to define a sum that contains derivatives of a function, where the summation index is the derivative order.
Simple example:

```
x, i = symbols("x i")
f = Function("f")(x)
Sum(diff(f,x,i), [i,1,3])
```

However, this only returns a sum of zeros. I assume this is because it tries to differentiate f wrt x first, and then wrt i. Since f is not a function of i, it evaluates to zero *before* it is processed by the Sum function. What I want to happen is

```
diff(f,x,1)
diff(f,x,2)
diff(f,x,3)
```

etc.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sympy.diff(f,x,i)` is equivalent to `i`'th order derivative of `f` only if `i` is an integer. In your case it is a symbol.

Use instead the builtin `sum()` along with a generator expression:

```
>>> sum(diff(f,x,j) for j in range(1,4))
Derivative(f(x), x) + Derivative(f(x), x, x) + Derivative(f(x), x, x, x)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sum(diff(f, x, j) for j in range(1, 4))`?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for catching that. I didn't pay much attention to that detail in the question after I overcame the essential problem.